# Suppressing the segfault signal

Tags: linux, bash, segmentation-fault, signals

I am analyzing a set of buggy programs that under some test they may terminate with segfault. The segfault event is logged in `/var/log/syslog`.

For example the following snippet returns `Segmentation fault` and it is logged.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ./test
```

My question is how to suppress the segfault such that it does *NOT* appear in the system log. I tried `trap` to capture the signal in the following script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -bm
 trap "echo 'something happened'" {1..64}
 ./test
```

It returns:

```
 Segmentation fault
 something happened
```

So, it does traps the segfault but the segfault is *still* logged.

```
 kernel: [81615.373989] test[319]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f6b9436d614 
 sp 00007ffe33fb77f8 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7f6b942e1000+1bb000]
```

Comment: Your shell script will probably receive a SIGCHLD. SIGSEGV is received by the sub-shell executing `./test`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `./test` to the following line:

```
. ./test
```

This will execute `./test` in the same shell.

Answer (score 0):

We can suppress the log message system-wide with e. g.

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/debug/exception-trace
```

- see also

- [Making the Linux kernel shut up about segfaulting user programs](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/ShuttingUpSegfaultSyslogs)
- [Is there a way to temporarily disable segfault messages in dmesg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243828/is-there-a-way-to-temporarily-disable-segfault-messages-in-dmesg)

---

We can suppress the log message for a single process if we run it under [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) control, as in a debugger. This program does that:

`exe.c`

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    if (*++args)
    if (pid = fork())
    {
        int status;
        while (wait(&status) > 0)
        {
            if (!WIFSTOPPED(status))
                return WIFSIGNALED(status) ? 128+WTERMSIG(status)
                                           : WEXITSTATUS(status);
            int signal = WSTOPSIG(status);
            if (signal == SIGTRAP) signal = 0;
            ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, signal);
        }
        perror("wait");
    }
    else
    {
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
        execvp(*args, args);
        perror(*args);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It is called with the buggy program as its argument, in your case

```
exe ./test
```

- then the exit status of `exe` normally is the exit status of `test`, but if `test` was terminated by signal *n* (11 for *Segmentation fault*), it is 128+*n*.

After I wrote this, I realized that we can also use `strace` for the purpose, e. g.

```
strace -enone ./test
```